# Disadvantages of using Java classes compiled using Java 6 JDK, in Java 8+ JVMs

Tags: java

Our java Application runs on Java 8 JVM. But we have some critical libraries compiled only in Java 6, can't recompile them anymore. Just wondering if there are any disadvantages of running those Java 6 classes in Java 8+ JVMs?

Comment: Should be fine. There are some cases of incompatible changes made to libraries, but they're few and far between. So long as your test suite is thorough and all your unit tests pass, you should be good to go.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases you will be fine- "old" bytecode can always be run on newer Java versions. Though if I remember correctly, we had some strange compatibility issues of this sort in the past, and it was with some old Scala libraries.(they were doing strange stuff with the bytecode).

Comment: There almost certainly will be no issues, unless the libraries are doing shady things like using undocumented classes in `com.sun` or messing with private fields in Java SE classes which may or may not still be present in Java 8.

Comment: It us unlikely that you will have problems.  Put it this way: if you cannot recompile the critical libraries then any "disadvantages" are moot ... unless they are show-stoppers.  And if there are show-stoppers, then you have no choice but to *rewrite* the libraries.  But if you do decide to rewrite them, that is an opportunity to improve them.

Comment: thanks for all the replies. These libraries do use lot of off heap storage based data structures. Does it change your opinion in any way?